# kill signal from a underpriviledged user to root user

Tags: multithreading, process, signals, kill

I have been bangin my head on this problem.

I want to send a kill(pid,SIGUSR1) signal to a process running in root user with a process
running in tom user.However everytime,I do this Operation not permitted comes up.

I searched up the net for any programmatical solution but to no avail.All responses are its impossible.But i am a bit skeptical and think it can be done programatically using c.

I need a sample program or lines which can explain how this can be acheived.

i tried using execl also.

To be more specific this kill signal is generated from mysql user to a process running in root and tried running in mysql aswell returned the same result operation not permitted.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a process with an [setuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) setting ?

Comment: yes i did try that ..didnt work either...i did setuid(0) and setuid(pid) where pid is the process id of the process..can u provide any example how to aceive it ..cuz i got the same result operation not permitted..

Answer (score 0):

The following is what you'd do from a unix/linux command line. Haven't used c in a while, but I'm pretty sure there's some "system" or "shell" function you can pass a shell command to.

If you can use sudo from your, that should do it:

sudo kill -9

Normally, you'd just need

kill -9

but some processes need more authority to kill.

You can get the process id with

ps -aux | grep

I'm afraid I don't know any more than that, hope this helps!
kyle